# Rails: link_to with remote true and opening it in a new tab or window

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link which, when clicked, will make an AJAX call. This AJAX call will result in a modal showing up.

```
= link_to edit_evaluation_path(evaluation), remote: true
```

However, when trying to open a new tab from the link (by clicking it with the middle mouse button, for example) I've been getting a `ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat` error, because the action is not expecting to respond with a html format. Here's the `respond_to` code from the corresponding action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

How can I prevent the user from opening the link in another tab or window? Am I obliged to change the `link_to` to a `button_to`? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've made created Javascript only solution for this problem in which I ran today.

```js
$.each($("a[data-remote='true']"), function(i, val) {
  $(val).data("url", $(val).attr("href")).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);")
});

$.rails.href = function(el) {
  var $el = $(el);
  return $el.data('url') || $el.data('href') || $el.attr('href');
}
```

It will replace all data-remote links on the site directly

Comment: This doesn't work when you have more than one action on the page. The second time you click it, it throws `GET javascript:void(0); net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: I'm sorry for the comment above. The thing is that the response from the remote action used to also contain this script inside. So, this can be improved to identify the already updated `url` field and skip them.

Answer (score 1):

I have devised a workaround for this. This comprises of two steps:

The jquery-ujs function that determines target url of a remote link can be overriden. So we override it to pick a data attribute before we check for href.

```
$.rails.href = function(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return $el.attr('data-url') || $el.attr('data-href') || $el.attr('href');
}
```

Next, We create a custom helper similar to link to that outputs the url in data attribute rather than href.

```
  def pseudo_link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    html_options, options, name = options, name, block if block_given?
    options ||= {}

    html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)

    url = url_for(options)
    html_options["data-href".freeze] ||= url
    html_options['href'] = 'javascript:void(0)'
    content_tag("a".freeze, name || url, html_options, &block)
  end
```

Note that actual href is `javascript:void(0)` which is a [javascript no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).

Now, all you have to do is use `pseudo_link_to` helper in your rails views instead of `link_to`.